# How to replace android library binary

Tags: android, android-source, android-firmware

I need to replace a shared obj `/system/lib/hw/bluetooth.default.so` on my Nexus 5X, by a different one that I built from AOSP source.

Nexus 5X runs MTC19T factory image and is rooted.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself.

Couple of methods would be to unpack+repack img files, or to create update.zip which I couldn't find guidance for.

Simplest way is to use TWRP recovery. It can modify system partition directly. So I copied file to /sdcard, then in TWRP, I moved it to correct location.

Comment: This results in a side-effect that replaced file was saved with `u:object_r:media_rw_data_file:s0` so `setenforce 0` is required before bluetooth will load this library.

Comment: this side-effect is mitigated if I `copy` instead of `move`

Comment: Also works: `adb remount`, followed by `adb push` to final location.